# A square matrix is called skew-symmetric if $A^T=-A$. Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are skew-symmetric matrices, then $A+B$ is skew symmetric.

Tags: matrices

A square matrix is called skew-symmetric if $A^T=-A$.
Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are skew-symmetric matrices, then $A+B$ is 
skew symmetric.

Comment: Please add your thoughts/partial work when you ask a question, in order for us to help you more specifically. You may want to visit [this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange) for more details and [this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to format your questions with mathjax.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$(A+B)^T = B^T + A^T = -B - A = -(B + A) = -(A + B).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrices skew-symmetric. Then
$$
(A+B)^{\top}_{ij} = (A^{\top}_{ij} + B^{\top}_{ij}) = (-A_{ij} - B_{ij}) = -(A+B)_{ij}
$$
for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n$,
*i.e.*
$(A+B)^{\top} = -(A+B).$